# Array group and sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to achieve is a messaging application, before you select the message conversation you want, you see a list of all the recent messages you've gotten, and a preview of the latest message you received/sent.

The problem is that my script iterates through the array and posts all the results, what I want to do is that it groups my phone number (`82784`) with the contacts and only shows 1 result per contact, and for contacts that are not in my contact list their `name` should be their phone number.

I've added two arrays, my contacts and the messages sent. As well as two images of how it looks and how it should look.

[How it looks at the moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNSvq.png)

[How I would want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAtx2.png)

**Contacts Array**

```
contacts = {
  [1] = {contact_name = "Rudolf Albinsson", contact_number = "32682"},
  [2] = {contact_name = "Svea Engström", contact_number = "94784"},
  [3] = {contact_name = "Theodor Sylvia", contact_number = "45270"},
  [4] = {contact_name = "Kai Catrine", contact_number = "12527"}
},
```

**Messages Array**

```
messages = {
  [1] = {message_sender = 32682, message_sender_name = "Rudolf Albinsson", message_receiver = 82784, message_receiver_name = "Ivanov Valkov", message_message = "Test 1", message_read = "0", message_datestamp = "2018-06-09 05:45:49"},
  [2] = {message_sender = 32682, message_sender_name = "Rudolf Albinsson", message_receiver = 82784, message_receiver_name = "Ivanov Valkov", message_message = "Test 2", message_read = "0", message_datestamp = "2018-06-09 05:46:12"},
  [3] = {message_sender = 82784, message_sender_name = "Ivanov Valkov", message_receiver = 32682, message_receiver_name = "Rudolf Albinsson", message_message = "Test 3", message_read = "0", message_datestamp = "2018-06-09 05:47:46"},
  [4] = {message_sender = 82784, message_sender_name = "Ivanov Valkov", message_receiver = 32682, message_receiver_name = "Rudolf Albinsson", message_message = "Test 4", message_read = "0", message_datestamp = "2018-06-09 05:48:01"},
  [5] = {message_sender = 32682, message_sender_name = "Rudolf Albinsson", message_receiver = 82784, message_receiver_name = "Ivanov Valkov", message_message = "Test 5", message_read = "0", message_datestamp = "2018-06-09 05:48:36"},
  [6] = {message_sender = 62649, message_sender_name = "Hamid Hamdi", message_receiver = 82784, message_receiver_name = "Ivanov Valkov", message_message = "Test 6", message_read = "0", message_datestamp = "2018-06-09 05:48:55"},
},
```

**Code**

```
for(let i = 0; i < PlayersData.messages.length; i++){
  if(PlayersData.messages[i].message_receiver == PlayersData.phone && PlayersData.messages[i].message_sender == contact_number){
     Contacts.find("ul.messages").append('<li class="contact">'+ PlayersData.messages[i].message_message +'</li>');
  }else if(PlayersData.messages[i].message_receiver == contact_number && PlayersData.messages[i].message_sender == PlayersData.phone){
     Contacts.find("ul.messages").append('<li class="me">'+ PlayersData.messages[i].message_message +'</li>');
  }
}
```

Comment: The arrays are sent from a `LUA` sript to a `JavaScript` page, so the arrays are in `LUA` and the code in `JavaScript`.

Comment: Those look like objects, not arrays.

Comment: What is `PlayersData`, and how does it relate to `messages`, `contacts`, and `Contacts`?

Comment: The arrays/objects posted are broken up basically, it's part of another array/object, listed here https://pastebin.com/Unh3gUyJ

Comment: I think you need to do some more on this question and convert it into an [mcve] without using external resources, they have a habit of disappearing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code that should help you.
You have to change the way you want to display data by replacing the console.log lines.

```
const handledSendersNumbers = []
// We run over all messages
for (let messageIndex = messages.length - 1; messageIndex >= 0; messageIndex--) {
    const message = messages[messageIndex]

    // We check that the number of the sender has not been handled yet
    // If it's not the case we have to display his message
    if (handledSendersNumbers.indexOf(message.message_sender.toString()) === -1) {
        // We look for a contact corresponding to the sender number
        let foundContact
        for (const contact of contacts) {
            if (contact.contact_number === message.message_sender.toString()) {
                foundContact = contact
                break
            }
        }

        if (foundContact) { // if a contact has been found, we display his name and the message
            console.log(foundContact.contact_name, message.message_message)
        } else { // if no contact has been found, we display his number and the message
            console.log(message.message_sender, message.message_message)
        }

        // We add the number of the sender to the liste of handled numbers
        handledSendersNumbers.push(message.message_sender.toString())
    }
}
```